# Drawing a horizontal line with limited length

Tags: pine-script

I have a dataset with a number of `dates` and a predicted `low/high` for that day.
For each day in my dataset, I'd like to plot a horizontal line from the start to the end of that session, indicating the predicted low/high.

Consider below image of a 15 minute chart of the SPX.
The blue lines are an example of a `low/high` plot for the session of `03/05/2020`.

[image]

My example dataset is in this format `[(Date1,Low1,High1),(Date2,Low2,High2),...]`

```
[(03/02/2020,2850,2950),(03/03/2020,2975,3050),(03/04/2020,3125,3225),(03/05/2020,3080,3160),(03/06/2020,2900,2960)]
```

Does anyone have an idea how to start building Pine code that could plot this?

Answer (score 0):

You can starts from this:

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © adolgov

//@version=4
study("My Script", overlay = true)

drawHiLo(y,m,d,h,l) =>
    var hl = line.new(0,h,1,h)
    var ll = line.new(0,l,1,l)
    prevDate = timestamp(year[1],month[1],dayofmonth[1],0,0,0)
    curDate = timestamp(year,month,dayofmonth,0,0,0)
    date = timestamp(y,m,d,0,0,0)
    dateEnd = timestamp(y,m,d+1,0,0,0)
    if prevDate < date and curDate >= date
        line.set_x1(hl, bar_index)
        line.set_x1(ll, bar_index)
    if bar_index > 0 and prevDate < dateEnd and curDate >= date
        line.set_x2(hl, bar_index-1)
        line.set_x2(ll, bar_index-1)

if bar_index > 0
    drawHiLo(2020,03,02, 2850,2950)
    drawHiLo(2020,03,03, 2975,3050)
    drawHiLo(2020,03,04, 3125,3225)
    drawHiLo(2020,03,05, 3080,3160)
    drawHiLo(2020,03,06, 2900,2960)
```